# Null pointer Exception for javax.enterprise.event.Event

Tags: jsf, maven, events, nullpointerexception, cdi

I am getting a null pointer exception when I am trying to fire an event in Java EE application. Below is the code in place.

`HelloEvent` event model:

```
package com.eventhandling;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.logging.Logger;


public class HelloEvent implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String message;
    private static Logger LOGGER=Logger.getLogger("Log");
    public HelloEvent() {
    }

    public HelloEvent(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "helloEvent toString";
    }


}
```

`HelloMessenger` managed bean:

```
package com.eventhandling;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.event.Event;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;


@ManagedBean(name = "messenger")
@SessionScoped
public class HelloMessenger {

    @Inject
    Event<HelloEvent> events;
    private static Logger LOGGER = Logger.getLogger("Log");

    public void hello() {
        LOGGER.info("hello called");
        LOGGER.info("events" + events);
        HelloEvent helloEvent= new HelloEvent("testEvent");
        LOGGER.info("helloEvent"+helloEvent);
        events.fire(helloEvent);

    }

}
```

`HelloListener` event listener:

```
package com.eventhandling;

import javax.enterprise.event.Observes;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@SessionScoped
public class HelloListener {

    public void listenToHello(@Observes HelloEvent helloEvent) {

        System.out.println("HelloEvent: " + helloEvent);

    }

}
```

JSF view `Welcome.xhtml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"    
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

    <h:head>
        <title>JSF 2.0 Hello World</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body bgcolor="white">
        <h3>JSF 2.0 Hello World Example - welcome.xhtml</h3>
        <h4>Welcome </h4>
        <h:form>
            <h:commandButton value="Fire Event" action="#{messenger.hello}"></h:commandButton>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Maven dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

When I click on the command button, then I get a `NullPointerException`. This is because the `events` property isn't being injected and remains `null`. How is this caused and how can I sovle it?

Logs on Tomcat boot:

```
Jan 30, 2014 4:43:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.27 using APR version 1.4
.6.
Jan 30, 2014 4:43:35 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], ra
ndom [true].
Jan 30, 2014 4:43:36 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initialize
SSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1d 5 Feb 2013)
Jan 30, 2014 4:43:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-6080"]
Jan 30, 2014 4:43:37 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-6006"]
Jan 30, 2014 4:43:37 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 3047 ms
Jan 30, 2014 4:43:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jan 30, 2014 4:43:37 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
Jan 30, 2014 4:43:37 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive D:\software\testtomcat_6080-_Analytics_w
ars\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\JavaServerFaces.war
Jan 30, 2014 4:43:43 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJar
File
INFO: validateJarFile(D:\software\testtomcat_6080-_Analytics_wars\apache-tomcat-
7.0.42\webapps\JavaServerFaces\WEB-INF\lib\jsp-api-2.1.jar) - jar not loaded. Se
e Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/el/Expression.class
Jan 30, 2014 4:43:43 PM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJar
File
INFO: validateJarFile(D:\software\testtomcat_6080-_Analytics_wars\apache-tomcat-
7.0.42\webapps\JavaServerFaces\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.5.jar) - jar not loaded
. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.cl
ass
Jan 30, 2014 4:43:46 PM com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener contextInitialize
d
INFO: Initializing Mojarra 2.1.7 (SNAPSHOT 20120206) for context '/JavaServerFac
es'
Jan 30, 2014 4:43:46 PM com.sun.faces.spi.InjectionProviderFactory createInstanc
e
INFO: JSF1048: PostConstruct/PreDestroy annotations present.  ManagedBeans metho
ds marked with these annotations will have said annotations processed.
Jan 30, 2014 4:43:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\software\testtomcat_6080-_Analytics
_wars\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\admin
Jan 30, 2014 4:43:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\software\testtomcat_6080-_Analytics
_wars\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\docs
Jan 30, 2014 4:43:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\software\testtomcat_6080-_Analytics
_wars\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\examples
Jan 30, 2014 4:43:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\software\testtomcat_6080-_Analytics
_wars\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\host-manager
Jan 30, 2014 4:43:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\software\testtomcat_6080-_Analytics
_wars\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\manager
Jan 30, 2014 4:43:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory D:\software\testtomcat_6080-_Analytics
_wars\apache-tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\ROOT
Jan 30, 2014 4:43:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-6080"]
Jan 30, 2014 4:43:48 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-6006"]
Jan 30, 2014 4:43:48 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 11372 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mixing up JSF and CDI concepts in one managed bean.

Use `@Named` and `@SessionScoped` but make sure you have the correct `@SessionScoped`. `@ManagedBean` should be removed. javax.enterprise.context is the package name. If you use the SessionScoped from JSF undocumented behavior will occur.

I am not sure about your dependencies but id depends on the container I guess. Please verify that CDI boots by reviewing your startup log. Make sure you have beans.xml in META-INF.

The log you pasted in the comment mentions nothing of either Weld nor OpenWebBeans and neither does your pasted dependencies in pom.xml. My conclusion is that you are  have not included CDI properly.

**What are your options?**

**Option 1**

Tomcat goes great with OWB / Weld but since OpenWebBeans share the same licence as your container and it's what I use I suggest that you add dependencies accordingly to these docs:
http://openwebbeans.apache.org/owbsetup_ee.html <--- Explains what you need in dependencies
http://openwebbeans.apache.org/download.html <--- Explains how to add to pom.xml

I wrote those docs, they are not perfect yet (sry) but it should get you going.

**Option 2:**
Switch to tomEE and only use provided in maven. This is the version of tomEE that includes everything you need. I really like tomEE and this is my default recommendation. The mailing list is really good and will get you going in no time if you have any issues.

**Option 3:**
Use Jboss Weld and follow their manual for getting started with Tomcat. Should be easy to find using google.

Comment: Thanks for your response..I made the changes as you mentioned. and used javax.enterprise.context for '@SessionScoped'. But I am getting the following exception :javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /welcome.xhtml 14,74 action="#{messenger.hello}": Target Unreachable, identifier 'messenger' resolved to null

I was getting this exception earlier as well, hence I used '@ManagedBean'..Please can you tell me the probable reason of this exception when I use '@Named("messenger")'  [import javax.inject.Named;]

Comment: Also can you tell me how to configure the beans.xml as the example I followed did not show any beans.xml..

Comment: In WEB-INF you need beans.xml. The file can be empty. Similarly you need beans.xml in any jar you have, put it in META-INF. It should be no problem for you to google up this information.

Comment: Just as you mentioned I had tried with beans.xml being placed in the WEB-INF folder. But still it didnt work..Giving the same exception.. Googled out and placed the following bean.xml in the WEB-INF folder and also individually in META_INF Folder

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="
       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_0.xsd">
</beans>`

Comment: Have it empty if you do not define anything in it. What container do you use? Does CDI boot during startup? show startup log from your container.

Comment: I use Tomcat 7. Here are the logs 
Have edited the post and added logs in it.